# Github API: add group as repo colalborator

Tags: github, github-api

I want to add a group as a collaborator to my github repo

Docs page is missing this part. I can successfully add a person as a collaborator using this request

```
curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/collaborators/USERNAME \
  -d '{"permission":"permission"}'
```

but when I want to add a group(created under same organization) – I can't

Is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to go from another end:

add repo to the team. Here are API references

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/teams#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions